# How to access stepExecution content in itermWriterListener Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I want to access StepExecution in org.springframework.batch.core.ItemWriteListener but not able to do that, i have tried to define local variable:

```java
    private StepExecution StepExecution;
```

and add below code:

```java
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.StepExecution = stepExecution;
    }
```

Seems beforeStep code never gets executed. is there anyway to access the context?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the annotation based approach, you don't need to implement listener interfaces, Spring Batch will create a proxy for each corresponding listener interface based on annotated methods. Here is a quick example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.AfterWrite;
import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.BeforeStep;
import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.BeforeWrite;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("myJob")
                .start(steps.get("myStep")
                        .<Integer, Integer>chunk(5)
                        .reader(new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)))
                        .writer(items -> items.forEach(System.out::println))
                        .listener(new MyListener())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
    
    static class MyListener {

        private StepExecution stepExecution;

        @BeforeStep
        public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
        }
        
        @BeforeWrite
        public void beforeWrite(List<? extends Integer> items) {
            System.out.println("About to write items " + items + " in step " + stepExecution.getStepName());
        }

        @AfterWrite
        public void afterWrite(List<? extends Integer> items) {
            System.out.println("Successfully wrote items " + items + " in step " + stepExecution.getStepName());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfiguration.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
About to write items [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] in step myStep
1
2
3
4
5
Successfully wrote items [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] in step myStep
About to write items [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] in step myStep
6
7
8
9
10
Successfully wrote items [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] in step myStep
```

In this example, Spring Batch will create a polymorph proxy (which implements both `ItemWriteListener` and `StepExecutionListener`) and you can register it only once in the step.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why it works with annotation but not with implementing ItemWriteListener? stepExecution is null in BeforeStep when I implement ItemWriteListener.

Comment: @Abhay You should also implement `StepExecutionListener` to achieve the same behaviour with interfaces, not only `ItemWriteListener`.